# How to extract path url using PHP

Tags: php

How can I extract path in url using php ?

example :

```php
text input = https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OJOZBBUCa5SsmUF3UdGJCk7A4t2kAHVr

output = 1OJOZBBUCa5SsmUF3UdGJCk7A4t2kAHVr
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php + https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_GET['id']`.

Or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get all the parameters.